# Generate CSR without any extra attributes in distinguished name (DN) except common name and country

Tags: glassfish, keytool

My domain provider only alowes me to set common name and country in CSR, but with keytool emty atributes will always be set to [Unknown].
Is there a poisibility to set these attributes emty?
Or can i generate CSR for glassfish with Openssl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to supply the `DN` value as you wish, instead of the `keytool` constructing it for you.

You could use the `-dname` option, like this:

> keytool -genkeypair -keystore test.jks -storepass password -dname 'CN=localhost,C=US' -keyalg rsa -keysize 2048